# How to shrink webpage to any size screen- I can't tell what I'm doing wrong

Tags: html, css

After learning a little bit of web development in one of my college classes I decided to give it a shot on my own and make my own webpage. I want it to serve as a virtual resume. I have it's visuals and styling set up and it looks good on my laptop screen however it's not adaptive to the screen size. I've looked at others similar question and have tried implementing their ideas (such as setting my wrapper div  width and height to 100%) but nothing works. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong. I'll provide an image of what it should look like in case your screen may be larger or smaller. [Webpage visual goals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbIXg.jpg)
[Github repo- development branch: branch1/land-page](https://github.com/jordynniara/jordynniara.github.io)
My HTML:

```
<!Doctype html>
   <html>
<head> 
    <title>Jordyn N. Smith</title>
    <!--JQuery Library-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- My CSS stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script|Poiret+One">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--Javascript file functionality -->
    <script type=text/javascript src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<!--Angular functionality-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="myCntrl.js"></script>
<div id=wrapper>
    <body onload="onload()">
        <!--Info Drawer-->
        <div id="infoDrawer" class="drawer" ng-controller="myCntrl" ng-app="myApp">
            <span class="drawerFont" id=information>{{Information}}</span>
            <!--Side navbar-->
            <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav col-lg-3">
                <a id=aboutMe class="menu-btn abt" ng-click="aboutMe()">About Me</a>
                <a id=skills class="menu-btn skill" >Skills</a>
                <a id=exp class="menu-btn exp" >Experience</a>           
                <a id=award class="menu-btn award" >Awards/Honors</a>
                <a id=contact class="menu-btn contact" ng-click="contacts()">Contacts</a>
                <a id=dlResume class="menu-btn dl" href="Resources/Resume-lastupdate1:31:17.docx.pdf" download>Download Resume</a>     
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Name and message-->
        <div class="col-lg-9 message">
            <div class="name">Jordyn Niara Smith</div>
            <div class="wel-message">Welcome to my page. Take a look around.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
/*Background image styling*/
body{
background-image: url(Resources/FaceQ.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat; /*don't repeat image*/
background-position: center top; /*position image in center from top*/
background-color: black !important; /*override default color value w/ image*/
/*height: 100%; fix height of page*/
/*position: fixed;*/
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
 min-width:900px;
min-height: 450px;
}

body#wrapper{
width:100%;
height: 100%;
}


/*Name and welcome message div styling */
div.name{
color:white; 
/*    text-align: center; */
font-size: 7em;
font-weight: bold;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive; /*googl font*/
text-shadow: 4px 4px 4px black;
width: 913px;
}
div.wel-message{
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-variant: small-caps;
font-size: 2em;
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 900px;
}
div.message{
/*keeps message fixed to center of screen*/
position: fixed;
/*
height: 200px;
width: 994px;
*/
height: 30%;
width: 90%;
margin: -100px 0 0 -200px;
top: 375px;
left: 458px;
}

/*nav bar styling*/
body div.col-lg-3{
padding: 0;
width: 278px;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
z-index: -1; /*position behind splash message*/
top: 200px; /*set position from top*/
left: 0;/*set position from left*/
}
div.sidenav {
height: 330px; /* 100% Full-height */
width: 278px; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
background-color: transparent;
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
}

a.menu-btn{
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;/*spaces out buttons*/
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; /*google font*/
font-size: 2em;
width: 100%;
float:left;
}

#aboutMe{
color:red;
} 
/*change color on hover */
a.abt:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color: red;
text-decoration:none;
}

#skills{
color:dodgerblue;
float: none;
padding-right: 70%;
}
a.skill:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color: dodgerblue;
text-decoration:none;
}

#exp{
color:greenyellow
}
a.exp:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color: greenyellow;
text-decoration:none;
}

#contact{
color:yellow;
}
a.contact:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color: yellow;
text-decoration:none;
}

#dlResume{
color: mediumpurple;
}
a.dl:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color:mediumpurple;
text-decoration:none;
}

#award{
color:darkorange;
}
a.award:hover{
color:white !important;
background-color: darkorange;
text-decoration:none;
}

/* The info drawer */
.drawer {
height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
width: 0; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
opacity: .9;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background-color:#111; /* Black*/
overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
padding-top: 60px; /* Place content 60px from the top */
transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
}
.drawerFont{
/*font styling*/
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; /*google font*/
color: white;
z-index: 1;
font-size: 4em;
}
```

Comment: You have a min-width of 900px on your body `min-width:900px;` so the entire page will never be less than 900px wide. You also have `width: 900px;` on the `wel-message` element. You have to use percentages not px values if you want things to adapt/respond.

Comment: You appear to have included Bootstrap, but don't actually use it properly. Got to getbootstrap.com and read through the documentation.

Comment: Also this class: body#wrapper will never be applied to anything. Your wrapper div needs to be inside the body and the selector needs a space: body #wrapper

Comment: So I changed the css to use percentage instead of pixels, but now minimizing the page just squishes everything together (which I kind of expected). Even after putting the wrapper inside the body the entire page doesn't shrink in unison. I want the entire page to shrink/enlarge as one unit with window resizing. How can I do that? @EdmundReed

Comment: @W.Scott anymore suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I added the background size attribute to the body a set it to a percent, and modified my font size to use vw instead of pixels or percent, and found it to be more adaptive to browser size. Now I just need to keep them from shift around...